# Link_to a named scope with attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

After an afternoon spending in web search. I have to ask you.

In my app I have a list of games which have one or more platforms associated. I want to propose to the user some filter based on the platform.

I know that I have to use named scopes with an attribute. But I don't know how to make link which

Comment: Hi, are you using `:has_many :games` in `Plataform` model?

Comment: `Has_and_belongs_to_many`to be precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `:has_and_belongs_to_many` a lazy way to do this is get all plataforms and game a uniq array of all game:

```
@games = @plataforms.map(&:games).uniq
```

If you use `:has_many`:

```
# in your game model
scope :by_plataforms, lambda { |plataforms_ids| where(:plataform_id => plataforms_ids) }
```

A sample call: `Game.by_plataforms([1, 2, 3])`

**EDIT**

To create a route you can use a param in your GamesController to filter by plataform:

```
def index
  @games = params[:plataform] ? Plataform.find(params[:plataform]).games : Game.all
end
```

And in the views:

```
<%= link_to games_path(:plataform => @plataform.id) %>
```

Comment: My problem is not how to make a scope I know it. But how can I make link in my view to filter my game list. Or to be simple how can I set the scope to use in my controller